# R modelsummary latex output - remove the \num{} tag

Tags: r, latex, modelsummary

For a series of models, I would like to create a latex table/output using the R package modelsummary.

The problem is that the package wraps the output values in the \num tag which seems to create problems with our latex table format. Is there anyway that the {estimates} output can just be the plain number?

Thanks for reading and for your help. Please ask for any additional infos.

Comment: Can you make a [mre] of your latex problems with `\num`? Maybe you could just redefine `\num` to avoid whatever problems you are facing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is documented in the "Global Options" section of the `?modelsummary` documentation:

https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/reference/modelsummary.html#global-options-1

This information also appears as a warning the first time you produce a LaTeX table in each session.

You can just do:

```r
options(modelsummary_format_numeric_latex = "plain")
```

After calling this, LaTeX tables should no longer wrap numbers in `\num{}`.